# solving non numerical matrix in matlab

Tags: matrices, matlab

I am trying to solve R1 and R2 on this [equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk31c.png)  in Matlab. I know that all term are constant except R1 and R2. I am trying to see online tutorial but all of them so far has numerical examples (rather than using letter as constant). I am sure there is tutorial about this on Youtube but I cannot find it because I do not know what is called. can you tell me what this method is called?

Comment: You want to use sym() and the syms shortcut to it. They are part of the symbolic toolbox.

Comment: @dbx thank you very much!